# Edge matching polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I am trying to match the edges of two polygon layers. One is Orleans county, NY and the other layers is Monroe county, NY. Since the Orleans county is from a different source, the boundaries are not matching. S_Pol_Ar is Orleans and Green outlined polygon is Monroes. Likewise, I have to match the boundaries with Niagara too.
Tried edge matching and reshape but they did not work.

[image]

Comment: Try Integrate, you can pass in multiple feature classes. Integrate modifies the input, you may want to backup your data first.

Comment: If Integrate is too big of a hammer (requiring too large a tolerance to generate high quality linework), you might want to research a tutorial on using a topology to drive manual editing of underlap and overlap between features where neither overlap or gaps are permitted.

Comment: klewis, intergrate both the layers? By integrate you mean intersect?

Comment: I tried to integrate and the output boundary of the rank 1 that is Orleans county is not matching with the boundary of Monroe county. Though the two boundaries when integrated(did the integrate on their respective copy of the boundary) did joined in with no gaps and with some gaps. But if I compare, its not giving good result.